# Find element neighbor

Tags: html, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have document with the following two formats:

```
<p><b>Referral Description:</b></p>
<p>
 This is the body of the referral's detailed description. 
 I want to get this text out of the document.
</p>
```

and

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b>FieldName:</b></td>
    <td>field value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Field2Name:</b></td>
    <td>field value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Field3Name:</b></td>
    <td>field value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In both cases, you can see that I need a value sitting in an un-named element, and its adjacent neighbor is a matching tag with a `<b>FieldName:</b>` body.

My question is, how can I use the neighbor tags to get the values I need? I can target the neighbor with

```
doc.xpath('//p/b[content(text(), "Referral Description:")]')
```

but how do I take that and say "Give me your neighbor"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do as below using [`Axis - following-sibling::`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-html
<p><b>Referral Description:</b></p>
<p>
 This is the body of the referral's detailed description. 
 I want to get this text out of the document.
</p>
html

node = doc.xpath('//p[./b[contains(text(), "Referral Description:")]]/following-sibling::p')
puts node.text
# >> 
# >>  This is the body of the referral's detailed description. 
# >>  I want to get this text out of the document.
```

**Or, using wild-card character `*` :**

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-html
<p><b>Referral Description:</b></p>
<p>
 This is the body of the referral's detailed description. 
 I want to get this text out of the document.
</p>
html

["Referral Description:", "FieldName:", "Field1Name:"].map |header|
  doc.xpath("//*[./b[contains(text(), '#{header}')]]/following-sibling::*')
end
# >> 
# >>  ["This is the body of the referral's detailed description.\nI want to get this text out of the document.", "field value", "field value"]
```

For the second part of HTML table :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b>FieldName:</b></td>
    <td>field value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Field2Name:</b></td>
    <td>field value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Field3Name:</b></td>
    <td>field value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
html

field_ary = %w(FieldName Field2Name Field3Name)
nodeset = field_ary.map{|n| doc.xpath("//td[./b[contains(.,'#{n}')]]/following-sibling::*")}
nodeset.map{|n| n.text }
# => ["field value", "field value", "field value"]
```

or(another approach)

```
nodeset = field_ary.map{|n| doc.xpath("//*[./b[contains(.,'#{n}')]]/following-sibling::*")}
nodeset.map{|n| n.text }
# => ["field value", "field value", "field value"]
```

Comment: I don't have Nokogiri installed, can you try if `following-sibling::*` works for both of OP's examples?

Comment: My point was if there is a wildcard that let's you use the SAME statement for both examples, without specifying `::p` or `::td`?

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant, +1.

Comment: @MichaelKohl Is there a way to also use the wildcard at the beginning of the xpath, e.g. `//*[./b[contains(...)]` or similar? The wildcard would have even more power in that case.

Answer (score 1):

In css, the next adjacent sibling selector is `+`:

```
doc.at('p:has(b[text()="Referral Description:"]) + p').text
```